# How to refresh content/UI in a custom alert dialog

Tags: android

The app has a custom dialogfragment, which has four *type* checkboxes and one *selectall* checkbox. When I select the *selectall* checkbox all the 4 *types* checkboxes should be ticked.

Now the *type* checkboxes are checked only when I reopen the dialogfragment. I want it all to be checked/unckecked as soon as I select/deselect the *selectall* checkbox.
Please look at my code and guide how to fix it.

**TypeDialogFragment.java**

```
public class TypeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private static final String TAG = "TypeDialog";
Context context;
public interface OnInputListener {
    void sendInput(String input);
}
public OnInputListener mOnInputListener;
View v;
.....
.......

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        //myList=getArguments().getStringArrayList("myListy");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    if (v != null) {
        if ((ViewGroup) v.getParent() != null)
            ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v);
        return v;
    }

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_restype_newdialog, container, false);

    //......

    type1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxS1);
    type1.setChecked(getFromSP("cbtype1"));

    type2 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxS2);
    type2.setChecked(getFromSP("cbtype2"));

    type3 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxS3);
    type3.setChecked(getFromSP("cbtype3"));

    type4 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxS4);
    type4.setChecked(getFromSP("cbtype4"));

    selectAll = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAll);
    selectAll.setChecked(getFromSP("cbselectAll"));

    type1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
                type1CBVal = "'S1'";
                saveInSp("cbtype1", true);
                MainActivity.myList.add(type1CBVal);
                mOnInputListener.sendInput(TextUtils.join(",", MainActivity.myList));

            } else {
                MainActivity.myList.remove("'S1'");
                mOnInputListener.sendInput(TextUtils.join(",", MainActivity.myList));
                saveInSp("cbtype1", false);
                saveInSp("cbselectAll", false);
            }
        }
    });

    type2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
                //....
                saveInSp("cbtype2", true);
            } else {
                ....
                saveInSp("cbtype2", false);
                saveInSp("cbselectAll", false);
            }
        }
    });

    type3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
                //....
                saveInSp("cbtype3", true);

            } else {
                //....
                saveInSp("cbtype3", false);
                saveInSp("cbselectAll", false);
            }
        }
    });

    type4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //is chkIos checked?
            if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
                //....
                saveInSp("cbtype4", true);

            } else {
                //....
                saveInSp("cbtype4", false);
                saveInSp("cbselectAll", false);
            }
        }
    });


    selectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //is chkIos checked?
            if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
                Log.i("klkl1", "checked");
                saveInSp("cbselectAll", true);
                tickTypes();
            } else {
                saveInSp("cbselectAll", false);
                untickTypes();
            }
        }
    });

    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
    params.x = 20;
    params.y = 250;
    window.setAttributes(params);
    return v;
}



public static void buttonEffect(View button){
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xe0f47521, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void untickTypes(){
    disableInSP("cbtype1",false);
    disableInSP("cbtype2",false);
    disableInSP("cbtype3",false);
    disableInSP("cbtype4",false);
}

public void tickTypes(){
    disableInSP("cbtype1",true);
    disableInSP("cbtype2",true);
    disableInSP("cbtype3",true);
    disableInSP("cbtype4",true);
}

private boolean getFromSP(String key) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}

private void saveInSp(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
private void disableInSP(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = window.getAttributes();
    windowParams.dimAmount = 0.00f;
    windowParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(windowParams);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
    try {
        mOnInputListener = (OnInputListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    Log.i("Dialog", "Destroyed");
    if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
        getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
    super.onDestroyView();
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ....
        typesImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog2");
                if (prev != null) {
                    ft.remove(prev);
                }
                ft.addToBackStack(null);

                final DialogFragment dialogFragment = new ResourceTypeDialogFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                //bundle.putStringArrayList("myListy", myList);
                //bundle.putBoolean("firsttime", firstTime);
                dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                dialogFragment.show(ft, "dialog2");
            }
        });

        }
```

Comment: `Now the checkbox is updated only when I reopen the dialogfragment` What you want instead of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this-

```
selectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //is chkIos checked?
        type1.setChecked(((CheckBox) view).isChecked())
        type2.setChecked(((CheckBox) view).isChecked())
        type3.setChecked(((CheckBox) view).isChecked())
        type4.setChecked(((CheckBox) view).isChecked())

        if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
            Log.i("klkl1", "checked");
            saveInSp("cbselectAll", true);
            tickTypes();
        } else {
            saveInSp("cbselectAll", false);
            untickTypes();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I completely missed `setChecked`. Thanks :)